# load Weka model in web application

Tags: web, weka

I have created and saved weka model that predicts disease according to the symptoms. So i want to integrate that model to a web application. The model should be accessed from the web app. That means user enters the symptoms from the web app and model should predict the result. How to do this. Is there any way to use saved weka model as API?

Comment: Yes, Weka has a Java API along with interfaces from various other languages.

Comment: Can we access this API from javascript. Can you share an example article.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a good documentation for the Java API, but I did find [some examples of using it in Java](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code). This link will unfortunately be broken soon as it looks like wikispaces is closing down.

Comment: But that is not Java-EE examples